# How to publish 2D array of int type

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How does one go about publishing a 2D array of the integer type in ROS?
I am using C++ for this node i am writing.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <sstream>
//include?

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");
 ros::NodeHandle n;
 ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::int>("chatter", 1000); //Is this correct?
 ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

 //define array
 data int[2][2];
 data[0][0] = 12;
 data[1][1] = 23;
  while (ros::ok())
  {
    chatter_pub.publish(data);
    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I have tried many things by now and I am really out of options. Anybody that can demonstrate this?

Simply said:
I would like the above code to be checked and edited so that it compiles without errors and that it sends a 2D array of type integer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275626/how-to-publish-2d-array-of-int-type/) by [CROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/32588/cros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-11**:\

> I have tried many things by now

then please tell us about that, as otherwise we run the risk of suggesting something you've already tried.

Please see the [Support Guidelines](http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Guidelines_for_asking_a_question_.28Please_read_before_posting.29).

**Comment by [CROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/32588/cros/) on 2017-11-11**:
@gdvhoorn, well honestly I would like the above way to work. This would be most convenient.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-11**:
Have you worked with ROS before? I only ask because it seems strange to expect to be able to publish arbitrary primitive data types. It's possible, but typically you go through / use specialised message structures.

And you didn't answer my question: what have you tried already that didn't work?

**Comment by [CROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/32588/cros/) on 2017-11-12**:
I have worked a little with ROS before, but that was only using simple string messages. And using predefined messages aswell. I have tried using int as shown above, I tried something similar with int16 and something with int16MultiArray. I have not tried making a specialized message..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you really need a 2D array (instead of a list or vector), take a look at #q234028. In essence: you'd use `std_msgs/Int32MultiArray` with suitable values for `size` and `stride`.

Another approach -- which would let you publish (but not subscribe to) actual `int[][]` arrays -- could be to use [message traits](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/MessagesTraits).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-12**:
And just a note: using something like `Int*MultiArray` as a message doesn't convey much semantics. If the array is really actually encoding some other domain concept, it might be better to explicitly model that (with a custom message) and send that.